# identifying source of issue with java_home environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a hadoop cluster like this in the latest version of ubuntu 64bit (vm):

```
hadoop launch-cluster MyCluster 1
```

this is the output that i get:

```
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I am setting this **JAVA_HOME** in **/usr/bin/hadoop** this way `export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")`

When I check the value of **JAVA_HOME**, i get **/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/**

line 320 of the file is:

```
JAVA_PLATFORM=`CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH} ${JAVA} -Xmx32m ${HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS} org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName | sed -e "s/ /_/g"`
```

and line 390:

```
exec "$JAVA" -Dproc_$COMMAND $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $CLASS "$@"
```

Why am I getting this message? **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `$JAVA` is probably set somewhere in your script to point to an older Java 6 binary. In this case it points to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java` which causes the shell to fail when running the commands. Set the `$JAVA` variable to point to the right location of your Java 7 binary and the problem should be solved.